# How to change logo on Ribbon menu VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ribbon-control

I saw ribbon menu at [VB Ribbon Control](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0cTlWg33P5w) .But I dont know how to change LOGO on top-left menu. Help me please. 
Thank for your help.
[image: LOGO Ribbon menu]